# Display Username and User Type after Logging IN. PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my login.php

```
 <form action="index.php" method=get>


      <?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
      ?>


    <?php
    session_start(); 
    if( $_SESSION["logging"]&& $_SESSION["logged"])
    {

    printme(); }



    else {
    if(!$_SESSION["logging"])
    {  
    $_SESSION["logging"]=true;

    loginform();
    }
    else if($_SESSION["logging"])
     {
     $number_of_rows=checkpass();
     if($number_of_rows==1)
   {    
    $_SESSION[user]=$_GET[userlogin];

    $_SESSION[logged]=true;

    echo "<h1>You have logged in successfully</h1><br/>";
    echo "<a  href='logout.php'>Logout</a> | <a href='users.php'>Click to proceed</a>"; 

                             }
                                else {



                            loginform();
                            }
                        }
                     }








    function loginform()
    {

    print ("<center><div id='login_header'><b><font face='Arial Black' color='black' size='4px'>Sign in to Minquep!</font></b></div></cen                   ter>");
    print("<br/><br/>");
    print ("<center><label>Username:</label><input type='text' name='userlogin' size='20'><br/><label>Password:</label><input type='                password' name='password' size='20'></center>");
    print "<br/><input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' class='submit'>"; 


    }


    function checkpass()
    {

    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUser = 'root';
    $dbPass = '';
    $dbname = 'minquep_test';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass); // Connection Code
    mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn); // Connects to database



    $sql = "select * from users where login='$_GET[userlogin]' and   password='$_GET[password]'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $fetched = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if ($fetched['user_type'] == "moderator"){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("You have logged in successfully!\n")</script>';
    echo "Welcome {$_SESSION['user']}";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=pages/moderator.php\">";
                    }
    if ($fetched['user_type'] == "agent"){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("You have logged in successfully!\n")</script>';
     echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=pages/agent.php\">";


                    }



                    }



        function content(){
        print("<b><h1>hi mr.$_SESSION[user]</h1>");
        print "<br><h2>only a logged in user can see this</h2>";



        }

       function printme(){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("You have logged in successfully!\n")</script>';
        }

        ?>




                </form>
```

Now whenever a user logs in... if his user_type is "moderator" he will be redirected to moderator.php

and if his user_type is "agent" he will be redirected to agent.php

what i want to happen is to output the username and usertype in the pages that a user will be redirected to.

This is what I've got in my agent.php and moderator.php

```
<?php session_start();

    echo "Welcome {$_SESSION['user']} . And You are Logged in as /*USER TYPE SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE */ ";

 ?>
```

I get this error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: I cannot even point to a particular issue, because all the code is sooooooooo wrong

Comment: check this line `$_SESSION[user]=$_GET[userlogin];` you didn't quote the `user` constant

Comment: @codingbiz: it wouldn't change anything (I'm not trying to argue that quotes should be placed there, but it wouldn't change behaviour of that particular line)

Comment: what specific codes are wrong

Comment: You're right. I know PHP would figure it out but it's bad. It's just a start.

Comment: @Xiruki Tepe: it is vulnerable to sql injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your agent.php

```
<?php session_start();

    if (array_key_exists('user', $_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['user'])) {

        echo "Welcome {$_SESSION['user']} . And You are Logged in as /*USER TYPE SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE */ ";

    } else {

        echo "Welcome stranger";
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: Not working. It always says stranger even if I log in as moderator or agent.

Am I doing the right thing in LOGOUT?

<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();

header("location: ../login.php");
?>

Comment: do a var_dump($_SESSION) in agent.php, what does it print? if it's empty your session handling is corrupt at all

Comment: how can i fix the issue using var dump? Should in go in logout.php or agent.php?

Comment: agent.php and post what it prints

Comment: still HELLO STRANGER. I put the var_dump($_SESSION); just before the echo "Welcome {$_SESSION['user']} . And You are Logged in as /*USER TYPE SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE */ ";

Comment: `var_dump` ALWAYS does some output. at least it should say `NULL` put the `var_dump` right after `session_start()`

Comment: After putting var dump . It echo... array (size=1)
  'logging' => boolean true

Welcome stranger

Comment: then you did not properly store the user in the session variable

Comment: Thanks for helping me out although it didnt work. I found another solution.... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different PHP files, `moderator.php` and `agent.php`, you may simply use;

In moderator.php,

```
echo "Welcome {$_SESSION['user']} . And You are Logged in as MODERATOR";
```

and in agent.php,

```
echo "Welcome {$_SESSION['user']} . And You are Logged in as AGENT";
```

No big tasks..

Comment: but it still doesnt recognize the index user... says the error

Comment: it says undefined: index user